# On the usage of the permutation tensor

Tags: tensor-calculus, vectors

The permutation symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is a set of 27 numbers, of values +1, -1 or 0 depending on $i, j, k$. I am familiar with the usage of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in the context of vector products, such as $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = \epsilon_{ijk}u_iv_j\mathbf{e}_k$, triple products or determinants. However, often times the tensor constructed from $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is given as an example of a third order tensor: $E = \epsilon_{ijk} \mathbf{e}_i \otimes \mathbf{e}_j \otimes \mathbf{e}_k$. I was wondering what this tensor is used for, as a tensor (rather than its elements as permutation symbols)? In particular, what would be a few examples of vector equations where $E$ appears as a tensor?

Comment: Isn't the cross product you wrote down an example? How is that not an example of using $\epsilon_{ijk}$?

Comment: So how would you write it in vector form? Something like $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = (E \mathbf{u}) \mathbf{v}$?

Comment: Sure, you could say $\mathbf{u} \times \mathbf{v} = E(\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \cdot)$, for example. (Here I'm neglecting the difference between covariant and contravariant tensors since you're in Euclidean space.)

Comment: thanks, I think that answers my question